# PyGObject custom widget: how to draw an invalidated region?

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, gobject-introspection

I know that you need to subclass `Gtk.DrawingArea` in PyGObject in order to create a custom widget. You then connect the `draw` signal to a callback that looks like this:

```
def on_draw(drawing_area, cr):
    # do something with cr
    return False
```

To ask for a redraw, you would call `my_widget.queue_draw()`.

Now, I know that you may ask to redraw a specific region of the surface using `my_widget.queue_draw_area()`. When your `on_draw` callback gets called after this, how do you know the region to draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `draw` virtual function is called with the invalidated area already part of the clip imposed on the Cairo context.

if you want to know the extents of the clipped region you can use the python wrapper for [gdk_cairo_get_clip_rectangle()](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cairo-Interaction.html#gdk-cairo-get-clip-rectangle).